# gluOrtho2D in webGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, projection-matrix

**UPDATE**: this code actually works.  My bug was a stray call to `glViewport`; that seems to be browser-window anchored and not canvas-relative in webGL and it was pushing everything off-screen.  So the code in this question shows how to create a correct orthogonal projection for WebGL:

webGL doesn't have `gluOrtho2D`.  I have copied - and transposed, as OpenGL matrices should be - from [`glOrtho`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```
function createOrtho2D(left,right,bottom,top) {
    var near = -1, far = 1, rl = right-left, tb = top-bottom, fn = far-near;
    return [        2/rl,                0,              0,  0,
                       0,             2/tb,              0,  0,
                       0,                0,          -2/fn,  0,
        -(right+left)/rl, -(top+bottom)/tb, -(far+near)/fn,  1];
}
```

I then set my projection uniform using `createOrtho2D(0,canvas.offsetWidth,canvas.offsetHeight,0)`.

For example, `createOrtho2D(0,1024,768,0)` =

```
[ 0.001953125,                      0,  0,  0, 
            0, -0.0026041666666666665,  0,  0, 
            0,                      0, -1,  0, 
           -1,                      1,  0,  1]
```

I upload this with `gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.program.mvp,false,mvp);` and in the vertex shader apply it with `gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertex,z,1.0);`.

However, this isn't working:

- The point 10,10 is not visible on the screen
- The point 10,100 is just about at the top of the screen

What have I got wrong?

Comment: I think there must be some other error somewhere. If I multiply (10,10,0,1) by your ortho matrix shown, I get (-0.98, 0.974, 0, 1), which should be right at the top left corner of the screen in NDC. Perhaps there is something else in your uniform creation/upload code, or shader that is causing the problem.

Comment: Your matrix looks ok, if I'm not missing something it's the same I use for my projection matrix.

Comment: Btw I recommend using https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix  there's no reason to reinvent the wheel